# How to have each EnumProperty item display a custom tooltip when using operator_menu_enum?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

The Blender UI for built-in operators shows custom tooltips for menu items shown using `operator_menu_enum`.

For example:

[image]

And the code looks like this:

[image]

But, whenever I try to add items to a menu using `operator_menu_enum`, Blender just displays the `__doc__` string from my Python class, while ignoring the `description` from my `items` tuple.

My example code:

```
 modifier_items = [
    ('solidify', 'Solidify', 'Add solidify modifier (custom tooltip, ignored)', 'MOD_SOLIDIFY', 1),
]

# ...

class CustomModifier(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add modifier (__doc__ string)"""
    bl_idname = "myops.modifier_add"
    bl_label = "Custom Modifier"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    modifier_type: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=modifier_items,
        name='Modifier Type',
        description='Type of modifier to add to mesh'  # this is also ignored
    )

# In the bpy.types.Menu subclass code:
# ...
layout.operator_menu_enum("myops.modifier_add", property="modifier_type", text="Add Modifier",)
# ...
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

---

### Edit

I originally posted the wrong image of the Blender built-in tooltips

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is 6 months old, but hopefully my answer helps some people.

First, you need to create a new variable above your enum. This variable contains your enum items.

Then, set the items in your enum variable to the items variable you declared above. This will act the exact same as you had it before, with the added benefit of being able to access the entire tuple of items later.

Next, there is a built-in classmethod called "description", it allows you to set the description of an operator at runtime. In this method, we are going to unpack our tuple of items and use it to get our description. We then return that description, which tells Blender to use it when we hover over the operator.

*The following code must be placed inside your operator class:*

```
enum_items = ("title1", "Title 1", "desc1"),
        ("title2", "Title 2", "desc2"),
        ("title3", "Title 3", "desc3"))

my_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = my_enum)

@classmethod
def description(cls, context, properties):
    items = {id: desc for id, name, *desc, in cls.enum_items}
    desc = items[properties.my_enum][0]
    return desc
```

Comment: looks like there's some bugs in your code
my_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = my_enum) should be my_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = enum_items)
and desc = items[properties.my_enum][0] should be desc = items[properties.my_enum][2]
but even in changing this it doesn't work, can you update your code ? thanks